# First query to MariaDB using ActiveRecord on JRuby takes over 5 minutes to execute

Tags: mysql, activerecord, jdbc, jruby, mariadb

Pulling my hair out over here trying to figure out what's going on...
Here's the setup:

```
Digital Ocean Droplet
Ubuntu 15.04.1 
JRuby 9.0.3.0
MariaDB 10.0.20
Java 1.8.0_66
```

Gems:

```
activerecord (4.2.4)
activerecord-jdbc-adapter (1.3.18)
jdbc-mariadb (1.2.0)
```

Here's the simple code I'm using to test:

```
require 'active_record'
require 'activerecord-jdbc-adapter'
require 'jdbc/mariadb'

Jdbc::MariaDB.load_driver

class Main < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection(
  :adapter  => "mariadb",
  :host     => "localhost",
  :database => "mydatabase",
  :username => "root",
  :password => "*******")
end

t1 = Time.now
puts Main.connection.execute("SELECT * FROM my_table")
t2 = Time.now
puts (t2 - t1) / 60

t1 = Time.now
puts Main.connection.execute("SELECT * FROM my_other_table")
t2 = Time.now
puts (t2 - t1) / 60
```

The results of this test are that the first query takes over 6.5 minutes to execute and the second is completed in a fraction of a second.

I have tried using MySQL instead of MariaDB with the same result. I have tried downgrading my gems as well as JRuby. I am seriously confused because locally it works as I would expect, the first query is returned almost instantly.

Help would be much appreciated thanks!

Comment: is the query cache enabled. so the second result is from cache

Comment: If I change the second query to ("SELECT * FROM my_other_table"), it still takes a fraction of a second

Comment: How many rows in each table?  Those queries would take minutes if there are millions of rows.

Answer (score 0):

usually indicates smt wrong with the production setup, it will be hard to tell exactly without knowing more about the provider and your specific setup.

you can verify its not a JRuby specific issue e.g. by trying a plain Java program to do the same, at that point you should likely raise an issue with support.